# Multiple inheritance, super() and their correct use with arguments in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to understand multiple inheritance in python. I think that "kinda" got it, but I'm missing a few pieces. I know that if I have two clases I can do something like:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
     
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,name):
        A.__init__(self,name)
        self.mm = False
        self.name = name

b = B("Peter")
```

My problem is when I have more classes and each class has their own init arguments. At first glance, it makes like no sense to have something like this:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,name,arg_a1,arg_a2):
        self.name = name
     
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,name,arg_b1,arg_b2,arg_a1,arg_a2...):
        A.__init__(self,name,arg_a1,arg_a2...)
        self.mm = False
        self.name = name

class C(B):
    def __init__(self,name,arg_c1,arg_c2,arg_b1,arg_b2,arg_a1,arg_a2.........):
        B.__init__(self,name,arg_b1,arg_b2,arg_a1,arg_a2...)
        self.name = name
```

So I started to look how to do it in an efficient way and not just hardcode it. Thats when I came across with multiple inheritance and thats when my doubts started to arraise.

If I have 3 classes:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,name,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.mm = False
        self.name = name
        
class C(B):
    def __init__(self,a,j,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.a = a
        self.j = j

c = C("p",1,5,name="p")
```

Why this give an error but adding name as an init argument does not?

In this other example, if I add another argument to A init's function the I get `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'name'`.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,name,lastname):
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
        
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,name,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(name,*args,**kwargs)
        self.mm = False
        self.name = name
        
class C(B):
    def __init__(self,a,j,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.a = a
        self.j = j

c = C("p",1,5,name="p")
```

So, after all this, several questions comes to my mind.

- Why this `TypeError` is generated?
- How can I make inheritance "smart"?
- Do I always need to use `*args` and `**kwargs` with multiple inheritance?

And all this gets me to the point to the libraries I use daily. Probably some of them use this concetps (I don't know, I'm assuming). What happes when the user puts a `kwarg` that is not present in any class? How do python "knows" that `name` goes in `class A` and not `class B` or viceversa?

Comment: I can't understand, your question is quite messy, kindly rephrase. Make it short and concise.

Comment: Just re-wrote all the questions.

Comment: In your example, the constructor of C uses the first 2 parameters. After that, in the constructor of B `name` is 5, `args` is empty, `kwargs` is `name="p"`. => multiple values for name.